# How to code zooming and panning for a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone

I have a UIImageView object, attached to a controller. It displays fine. What is a easy way to get zooming and panning with the least amount of code? Perhaps some library out there that does this? Hard to believe the SDK does not provide anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your UIImageView as a subview of a UIScrollView and make sure you change the `minimumZoomScale` or `maximumZoomScale`.

Also take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/maximumZoomScale) for UIScrollView there might be other settings you want to tweak.

Answer (score 1):

[UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) is the SDK class you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

The Three20 project has a photo viewer you may want to look into, that I believe supports zooming and panning in a larger image.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}
```

Here is some code

http://www.redcodelabs.com/2009/09/objective-c-zoom-image/

Comment: This seems to be a spam website now.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @OliverMason, insdded this is a old post and the url is not valid any more. I have updated my post